# JSON Многомерный массив в таблицу PHP

Tags: php, массивы, json

Имеется многомерный массив с элементами вида:

```
"orders": [
    {
        "id": 84297683,
        "items": [
            {
                "prices": [
                    {
                        "total": 165.00
                    },
                    {
                        "total": 658.00
                    }
                ],

            }
        ],
        "payments": [
            {
                "total": 658
            },
            {
                "total": 165
            }
        ],
        "commissions": [
            {
                "predicted": 6.58
            },
            {
                "predicted": 32.92
            }
        ]
    }
```

Как мне его с помощью PHP преобразовать в таблицу, в которой для каждого значения подмассивов items[prices], payments и commissions была бы строка с соответствующими значениями полей родительского массива (id и тд)?  причем количество значений в подмассивах всегда разное.

Пробую так:

```
$Res = json_decode($JSON, true);

if (isset($Res) and !empty($Res)) {
    foreach ($Res['orders'] as $order){
        if (isset($order['payments']) and !empty($order['payments'])) {
                foreach ($order['payments'] as $payment){
                    $orderid = $Res['orders']['id'];
                    $paymentstotal = $payment ['total'];
                
                }
            
        }
    }
}
```

но orderid всегда null

Comment: Ну, "в лоб" - перебираете массив, вытягиваете нужные вам элементы и вставляете их в таблицу. Квкой из этих пунктов вызывает затруднение?

Comment: А при чём тут тег [SQL]?

Comment: @Zombotron, затруднение вызывает именно переборка массива. Не пойму как во вложенных циклах foreach получить доступ к полям родительского массива.

Comment: `json` to `array`, `foreach`

Comment: @Zombotron, c первым понятно. непонятно со вторым. Добавил пример кода

Comment: $orderid = $order['id'];

Comment: @ВикторКарев, спасибо! Я протупил :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$orderid = $order['id'];
```

(с) ВикторКарев

Answer (score 0):

```
echo'<table  cellspacing="0" border="2" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 200px">';
echo'<thead>';

foreach ($Res['orders'] as $key => $order) 
{
echo'<tr>';
echo '<td style="width: 150px; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap">'.$order['id'].'<td style="width: 108px;">'.$order['payments'].'<td style="width: 107px;">'.$order['kash'].'<td style="width: 20px;">'.$order['sum'].'<td style="width: 38px;">'.$order['sum'].'<td style="width: 68px;">'.$order['total'].'<td style="width: 105px;">'.$order['login'].'<td style="width: 230px;">'.$order['reserv'].'<td style="width: 50px;">'.$order['name'].'<td style="width: 50px;">'.$order['soname'].'</td>';
echo'<tr>';
}
echo '</thead>';
echo'</table>';
```

Comment: Это подходит для одномерного массива.

Comment: делай ещё цикл, посмотри на структуры таблиц сложных, когда идёт разбивка или объединение столбцов. А потом уже когда поймешь структуру tr td th там уже и в цикле можно сделать в том числе со вложенными массивами.